# Change line of the multi-line commands in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

How can I change the line of multi-line command in terminal of Linux??

for example, I want to change Referer address of this cURL, but I can not do that in terminal and I have to go to some software like Gedit and change that and after that copy it in terminal... (SO BAD...)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKSmj.png)

Comment: The linux tag is specifically for coding questions relating to linux based OS's this kind of question would be much better asked on SuperUser

Comment: does  `sed` suit your purposes to change the value? Perhaps some awk could also be worth taking a look at.

Comment: And welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks for your help and I am sorry about linux tag, This question is my first